# Appium Camera Image Injection

Tags: appium, android-camera, appium-android, appium-ios, ios-camera

Majority of cloud device farms provide Camera Image Injection feature in both ios and android (with some exceptions)

- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/appium/advanced-features/camera-image-injection
- https://help.perfecto.io/perfecto-help/content/perfecto/automation-testing/image_injection.htm
- https://docs.saucelabs.com/mobile-apps/features/camera-image-injection/

I tried googling & finding how this is achieved. I couldn't find how this is being achieved or can find open source alternatives.

Could you amazing folks, please nudge me right direction on how this is being achieved. Im try to implement this in our in-house device farm. Any help in this regard would be of great help. Thank you!

Comment: Did you have any luck finding a solution?